# C++ : Is it possible to add multiple gRPC service definition in single proto file

Tags: c++, server, client, protocol-buffers, grpc-c++

I am trying to understand how the gRPC services are created and servers are linked to them, if **multiple** services are defined in **1 proto file**. (pls excuse for the long message)

With example from [this](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/basics/) documentation, I created basic server (1 service defined in 1 proto file) and was able to run the client application.

**Service Definition** in `route_services.proto`

```
service RouteGuide {
  rpc GetFeature(Point) returns (Feature) {} 
}

message Feature {
  // The name of the feature.
  string name = 1;

  // The point where the feature is detected.
  Point location = 2;
}
```

**Sample Server Code Snippet** in `route_guide_server.cc`

```
class RouteGuideImpl : public RouteGuide::Service {
...
// implement the service GetFeature
...
}
```

However, I am wondering if it's possible to have **more than 1 service** in 1 proto file and implement it's interface in Server like this below.

**Update Service Definition** in `route_services.proto` (note: RouteGuidanceV2 service and NewFeature message)

```
service RouteGuide {
  rpc GetFeature(Point) returns (Feature) {} 
}

message Feature {
  // The name of the feature.
  string name = 1;

  // The point where the feature is detected.
  Point location = 2;
}

/////////////////// Newly Added Service ///////////////////
service RouteGuideV2 {
  rpc GetFeature(Point) returns (NewFeature) {} 
}

message NewFeature {

  // The point where the feature is detected.
  Point location = 1;
}
```

**Update Server Code Snippet** in `route_guide_server.cc` (note: RouteGuideV2 class is inherited here)

```
class RouteGuideImpl : public RouteGuide::Service, public RouteGuideV2::Service {
...
// implement the service GetFeature (coming from RouteGuide interface)
// implement V2 service GetFeature (coming from RouteGuideV2 interface)
...
}
```

However, I am seeing this error : `‘grpc::Service’ is an ambiguous base`.
It occurs when compiling the server file (particularly at line where I am calling `builder->RegisterService(this)` to register my class `RouteGuideImpl`)

> From `protoc` compiler stand point, the **updated proto file** is also **valid**, and it generates the server and client code without any issue.

Assuming that, defining 1 service in 1 proto file seems to be an ideal way and works just fine, I would like to ask few questions on this topic to understand the common practices from gRPC users.

1. Is it not possible to derive multiple gRPC service class into single class to implement it's service methods ?? It may not be the best way to do it but I mean technically, it should be possible to override and implement gRPC virtual methods coming from 2 different service interfaces (1 each).
2. If RouteGuideV2 service `GetFeature` is functionally same with minor change in response message (Feature --> NewFeature), then doesn't it makes sense to define it in same proto file `route_guide.proto` instead of separate `route_guide_v2.proto` file?
3. If it's not correct to define several services, then what's the `recommended` way to add similar services  ?? (or is there any limitations on how services should be define and run by server)

Thanks for reading, waiting for responses...!!

Answer (score 0):

I would usually recommend creating separate proto files for different services just to keep it more modular, but I don't see a reason why you cannot do that. I just tried adding another service definition, and it worked.

> Is it not possible to derive multiple gRPC service class into single class to implement it's service methods ?? It may not be the best way to do it but I mean technically, it should be possible to override and implement gRPC virtual methods coming from 2 different service interfaces (1 each).

I think you are simply running into the issues of multiple inheritance where there is ambiguity since 1) both classes would be exporting methods with the same name and 2) the diamond inheritance problem.
Here, I would simply suggest that you prefer composition over multiple inheritance. Create two separate service implementations (one for RouteGuide, and one for RouteGuidev2), and have the actual business logic in a separate class.